# How to create dynamic sized Eigen::Matrix of double RowMajor?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, eigen, eigen3

Its said to use dynamic size to perform bigger https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html, how to create it for `RowMajor`?

I have this (which I guess is fixed size ?)

```
Matrix<double, N, N, RowMajor> m;
```

I think for (default) `ColMajor` answer will be `MatrixXd m(N,N);`. What about `RowMajor`?

Where `const int N = 1000;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Matrix<double, N, N, RowMajor> m;` will create a RowMajor matrix of a fixed size (NxN, assuming N is known at runtime). If you want it to be dynamically sized, use `Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor> m;` instead.